# Awesome wm doesn`t assume correct locale

Tags: locale, awesome-wm

I upgraded my Ubuntu to bionic (from xenial) recently and everything seems to work just fine, except that locale in awesome doesn't seem to work. In Ubuntu`s default window manager I configured it and it worked as expected.

In awesome, however, none of the locale-related command I run seems to change my locale. In `localectl` command, it does show what would be the correct locale, `System Locale: LANG=pt_BR.UTF-8`, but in the `locale` command, `LANG=en_US.UTF-8` and nothing seems to change that (granted, `export LANG=en_US.UTF-8` does, but it doesn't help).

This is a pain, as I need a host of keys that don`t show up in en_US.

I would appreciate any help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is not a task to awesome to change locales. Check your DM configuration. Note: terminal could set also own terminal (if it is in `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile`). And use `'`, not `\`` in English text.

Comment: I guessed it isn't awesome's task to change locales, but this is happening in awesome only... It also doesn't seem to be terminal related (I don't have locale related configs in my .zshrc, and it's always worked fine, and still does out of awesome). This started after system upgrade, so I guess it has something to do with awesome's version. obs.: sorry for the ` showing up in incorrect places.. I'm not used to this key's place